# Tootsie Roll Flavor

Tags: candy

Tootsie rolls dont quite taste like chocolate. They have a "cocoa" and "subtle fruit flavor" according to their website. What are the fruit flavors that makes them so unique? I've seen orange extract listed for homemade versions but that doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: No, they don't taste at all like chocolate to me. Years ago, wondering why I hate the taste of Tootsie Rolls so much, I read the ingredients. At that time, they listed molasses. That explained it perfectly at that time.... Don't know about now.

Comment: For whoever voted to close -- "What are the fruit flavors that makes them so unique?" is not opinion based.  Now, if we were trying to describe the flavor of wine, *that* would be opinion based.  ("stone fruit with vanilla and a touch of pepper" ... wtf?)

Comment: Are you sure you aren't seeing the flavorings for the fruit flavored tootsie rolls? https://www.amazon.com/Tootsie-Fruit-Rolls-Assorted-Flavors/dp/B000Q6R05G These are not chocolate flavored at all.

Comment: @Catija no Im not making that mistake

Comment: this question belongs on Philosophy SE.  Rilly.  The taste of an orange is natural.  The taste of a tootsie-roll is *sui generis* and man-made.  and sublime.  see also "Nutella" and "Marmie".

Comment: marmite,  not marmie.

Answer (score 1):

Tootsie rolls are taffy (sugar boiled with butter/oil, a lot like caramel but lighter in texture) flavored with cocoa powder and "natural and artificial flavorings".

It gets a light chocolate flavor from the cocoa powder. The flavorings are a trade secret which probably does include some sort of citrus flavor, among many others.